# TSLint not recognizing updating of array inside subscribe method

Tags: angular, warnings, tslint

In my Angular project, I'm getting a *Mismatched query and update of collection* error from TSLint when I write the following code:

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
    private wishes: Wish[];

    constructor(private service: Service) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.service.subscribe(wishes => {
            this.wishes = wishes;
        }
    }
```

I get a *Contents of collection 'wishes' are queried, but never updated* (I query it further down in the code). However, I don't understand why I'm getting the error since I'm updating the collection every time I receive wishes from my subscription. Does it have something to do with the update happening inside the subscribe block?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: ``this.service.subscribe`` this seems a bit wrong - did you remove some code before putting here? It looks like you subscribe directly to the service.

Comment: because it's private. Remove the private. If you use private in your global variables and don't have getters and setters is not good practice.

Comment: @Buczkowski you're right, I removed some code, that's why it looks weird.

Comment: @PatricioVargas Removing the private modifier solved it. I thought that it was only used privately, but I guess since I'm using it in the subscription block, it is also used outside the class. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the private. If you use private in your global variables and don't have getters and setters is not good practice.

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
    wishes: Wish[];

    constructor(private service: Service) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.service.subscribe(wishes => {
            this.wishes = wishes;
        }
    }
}
```

Using getters and Setters:

```
    export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
        private wishes: Wish[];

        constructor(private service: Service) {}

        ngOnInit() {
            this.service.subscribe(wishes => {
                setWishes(wishes);
            }
        }

       getWishes(): Wish[] {
         return this.wishes;
       }

       setWishes(wishes: Wish[]) {
         this.wishes = wishes;
       }
    }
```

depending on the server that you run it can potentially give you prod issues, by using privates, so I would stick to the first solutions.

you can run `ng build --prod` to test the code for prod